# values and keys guaranteed to be in the consistent order?

Tags: dictionary, julia

When applied to a `Dict`, will `values(...)` and `keys(...)` return items in matching order?

In other words, is `zip(keys(d), values(d))` guaranteed to contain precisely the key-value pairs of the dictionary `d`?

Comment: I'll note that in the definition of the dictionary type in the source code (https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/dict.jl) the keys and vals are stored as Array objects, which are ordered.  Thus, I am pretty sure they will be guaranteed to maintain their ordering, but I couldn't swear to it.

Comment: Note also the `OrderedDict` type in the `DataStructures` module.  This one definitely is guaranteed to maintain the ordering you want.  There's a bit more overhead, but not much.  And, since you're not relying on an "under-the-hood", undocumented issue in the source code being maintained the same through versions, it's probably a bit safer.

Comment: @MichaelOhlrogge Yes, looking at `dict.jl` I see that `values(Dict)` and `keys(Dict)` simply iterates the `Dict` and extract the key or the value respectively of each element. Therefore they are in the same order. It would be nicer though if this were guaranteed in the documentation. Hopefully it won't change in the future.

Comment: You could certainly post to GitHub with a request like this.  Ismael's answer includes a bunch of links to similar, pertinent discussions.

Comment: [corresponding issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/18090)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Option 1**

The current Julia source [code](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/dict.jl) indicates that the keys and vals of a `Dict()` object are stored as `Array` objects, which are ordered.  Thus, you *could* just use `values()` and `keys()` separately, as in your question formulation.  But, it is dangerous to rely on under the hood implementation details that aren't documented, since they might be changed without notice.

**Option 2**

An `OrderedDict` from the `DataStructures` package (along with the functions `values()` and `keys()`) is probably the simplest and safest way to be certain of consistent ordering.  It's ok if you don't specifically need the ordering.

**Option 3**

If you don't want to deal with the added hassle of installing and loading the  `DataStructures` package, you could just use Julia's built in syntax for handling this kind of thing, e.g.

```
Mydict = Dict("a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 1)

a = [(key, val) for (key, val) in Mydict]
```

The use of `zip()` as given in the question formulation just adds complexity and risk in this situation.

If you want the entities separate, you could then use:

```
Keys = [key for (key, val) in Mydict]
Values = [val for (key, val) in Mydict]
```

or just refer to `a[idx][1]` for the `idx` element of `Keys` when you need it.

Comment: For Option 3, you could do `collect(Mydict)`, which will turn the dictionary into an array of pairs.

Answer (score 5):

Currently your assertion seems to be true:

```rb
julia> let
           d = [i => i^2 for i in 1:10_000]
           z = zip(keys(d), values(d))
           for (pair, tupl) in zip(d, z)
               @assert pair[1] == tupl[1] && pair[2] == tupl[2]
           end
           info("Success")
       end
INFO: Success
```

But that is an undocumented implementation detail as Michael Ohlrogge explains.

Stefan Karpinski comment about *show(dict) now sorted by key* in [#16743](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/16743):

> This has performance implications for printing very large Dicts. I don't think it's a good idea. I do, however, think that making Dict ordered is a good idea that we should go ahead with.

See also:

- [#10116](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/10116) **WIP: try ordered Dict representation**.

Most importantly, what are you trying to do? Perhaps an `OrederedDict` is what you need?

Comment: I don't care about the `Dict` being ordered. What I want is that the order returned by `keys` (whatever it is) is consistent with the order given by `values`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, `keys` and `values` return items in matching order. Unless, as Dan Getz pointed out above, the dictionary is modified in between using the two iterators.

I think it would be relatively perverse for a dictionary not to have this behavior. It was obvious to us that the order should match, to the point that it didn't even occur to us to mention this explicitly in the documentation.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to state this explicitly in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to ensure corresponding order between keys and values is using `imap` from the Iterators package in the following way:

```
using Iterators
d = Dict(1=>'a',2=>'b',3=>'c')

# keys iterator is `imap(first,d)`
julia> collect(imap(first,d))
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 2
 3
 1

# values iterator is `imap(last,d)`
julia> collect(imap(last,d))
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 'b'
 'c'
 'a'
```

This method can potentially be adapted for other structures. All the other comments and answers are also good.

Comment: Of course, the dictionary cannot be modified between iterating on values and keys. Moreover, the dictionary iterator needs to be deterministic (one can imagine randomized or non-constant order of iterating on a dictionary) - currently this is true. Finally, the suggested method is relatively efficient in runtime and memory.